# Drop Usual Table and Temporary Table in one Mysql Command

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I have 3 tables in my database, consisting of 2 usual tables and 1 temporary table. How to drop all of these tables together in one MySQL command?

All of these tables were successfully deleted.

Comment: `DROP TABLE` drops both static and temporary tables.

Comment: Why do you want to drop tables which are successfully deleted?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

> DROP TEMPORARY IF EXISTS name_table; DROP TABLE name_table1, name_table2;

and hit enter

Answer (score -1):

To delete multiple tables, just specify them in a single drop table statement.  With the TEMPORARY keyword, all the tables specified must be temporary, but if you leave it off, DROP TABLE will first look for temporary tables and then permanent tables.  So this:

```
create temporary table x (id serial);
create table y (id serial);
create table z (id serial);
drop table x, y, z;
```

will delete all three tables.

You don't appear to be able to drop both a temporary and permanent table with the same name in the same command.

Comment: *You can't delete multiple tables in one command* ??? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-table.html *DROP TABLE removes one **or more** tables*.

Comment: @Akina wow, I never knew that.  thanks